Difficult to get the exact number for Offset value in flutter widget

Currently i'm trying to create an animation showed in above by using SlideTransaction with Offset. My circle is not moving to exact topMost corner as i'm using the static number of end Offset in Tween. How can i calculate to get the exact number of the offset to move the circle to topmost corner regardless of white rectangle width and height. The parent widget with and height may change according to user phone size.

Can you show the code?  There are many tools to compute point positions in the paint library.

You might want AlignTransition instead of SlideTransition.  Then you can animate from .center to .topRight.
